# Starting same main javascript form diffrent url's using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

For my webapp i use an MVC setup and so i only use 1 bootstrap script for starting my app. My `.htaccess` replies all requests with my index.html. This starts the bootstrap.js and everything goes fine aslong as i go to my page form `baseaddres.com` or form `baseaddress.com/anythinghere` but at the 2nd '/' requirejs (that would be `baseaddress.com/anything/here`) seems to not parse the base url proper.

My question would be: Is there a way to change this properly or do i have a setup error?

My bootstrap.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths:{
        'backbone':'JSLib/backbone',
        'underscore':'JSLib/underscore',
        'jquery':'JSLib/jquery'
    }
});

define(['underscore','backbone'], function(){

    ... // My code here
});
```

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mock login page</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script data-main="js/App/base/bootstrap.js" src="js/JSLib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write Login page</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I.E. `baseaddress.com/this/is/an/example` gets resolved to `baseaddress.com/this/is/an/` which is not the base address

Comment: Can you post example of wrong `baseUrl` resolving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `/` before `js/App/base/bootstrap.js` and `js/JSLib/require.js`

This because a first `/` indicates 'from root' which is `baseaddress.com`